# Problems with datatable using jQuery and perl

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, perl

I need help with my Datatable data processing

Am having a problem with my Script below of Server Side Processing (Datatable) its not displaying the data from backend script

The problem it just hangs on processing while not displaying the data from backend script

This is my backend script, its working and returns

```
{"748847":"Jane Deo"}
```

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -wT

use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;
use JSON;
use CGI qw/:standard/;

my $Cgi = CGI->new();

my $host =   "host";
my $usr =    "user";
my $pwd =    "pwd";
my $dbname = "datname";


my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:$dbname:$host", $usr, $pwd, {
                                  RaiseError => 1,
                                  }) or die $DBI::errstr;
                                  
my $Test = $dbh->prepare("SELECT idnum, fname FROM dbuser");
$Test->execute();


my (@data,$idnum,$fname);
 
 
 foreach (@data = $Test->fetchrow_array()) {
    $idnum = $data[0];
    $fname = $data[1];

}


my $json = encode_json(
  { $idnum, $fname}
);
print $Cgi->header( -type => 'application/json' ),$json;
```

And this is my html front end

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs-3.3.7/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script>
        jQuery(function($){
            $("#table_id").DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": "file.pl"
            });
            
        });
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>sample dataTable</h1>
    <table id="table_id" class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>NAME</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you see in the browser "Network" developer tool? Is an HTTP request issued to your server code? Does a response arrive? What's in it?

Comment: You need to check the **Network** tab, that's where the error will be clearly reported.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: c is undefined
    vb https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.js:56
    lb https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.js:53
    i https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.js:51
 ..............................

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: c is undefined
    vb https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.js:56
    lb https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.js:53
    i https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.js:51
    success https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.js:52
    u https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.js:14
    fireWith https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.js:14

Comment: Try defining the columns your DataTable is using, like so (apologies for making this minified): `jQuery(function($){ $("#table_id").DataTable({"processing": true,"serverSide": true,"ajax": "file.pl","columns": [{ data: 'id',orderable: true},{ data: 'name',orderable: true}]});});` . And in your *.pl script, you can create an associative array, and then convert it into a json string: `my %arr = ("id" => $idnum,"name" => $fname); my $json = encode_json(\%arr);`.

Comment: it still shows the same error:    Uncaught TypeError: c is undefined
    vb https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.js:56
    lb https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.js:53
    i https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.js:51
    success https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.js:52

Answer (score 0):

Some questions you should get the answers to:

1. **Ajax call** - Is `file.pl` being called correctly? Is just `file.pl` the correct URL for the CGI program? Do you see the request in the web server access log? Is there anything (particularly a 404 error) in the web server error log?
2. **CGI program call** - Is the web server configured correctly to execute `file.pl` as a CGI program? Is there anything useful in the web server error log (maybe something about permissions errors, and maybe a 500 error of some kind)?
3. **Data returned** - do you see the expected data returned in the network tab of the developer tools in your browser? Is that the correct data format for the way you have configured DataTables? Are you sure you don't want `{ "id" : "...", "name" : "..." }` instead?